# Issue seeding model.ts to mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, backend

so i'm connected to my mongodb atlas. i'm trying to seed data into my db.
the errors that i'm getting when i run `npm run seed` is:

`import connectDB from "../config/config"; ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

and this is my seeder.ts code snippet:

```
import connectDB from "../config/config";
import { JobModel } from "../models/model";

const loremIpsum = require("lorem-ipsum").loremIpsum;
const jobTitle = ["Frontend Developer", "Backend Developer"];
const salary = [2000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000];
const technologies = [
  "React",
  "Vue.js",
  "Angular",
  "JavaScript",
  "Python",
  "Java",
  "TypeScript",
  "MongoDB",
];
const NUM_OF_JOBS = 10;
const randomizeIndex = (arrLength: any) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * arrLength);
};

connectDB().then(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_OF_JOBS; i++) {
    const newJob = await JobModel.create({
      title: jobTitle[randomizeIndex(jobTitle.length)],
      description: loremIpsum(),
      responsibilities: loremIpsum(),
      requirements: loremIpsum(),
      salary: salary[randomizeIndex(salary.length)],
      technologies: technologies[randomizeIndex(technologies.length)],
    });
    console.log("newJob", newJob);
  }
});
```

i have exported my config file as such:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

// Create a new MongoClient
const connectDB: Function = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI as string);
    console.log(`db connected, ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in connecting to db");
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

export default connectDB;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

i tried to switch to const/require, but i read somewhere that TypeScript prefers import/from.

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo or Add all of your code and show us `package.json` file ?

Comment: Hello! This is my GitHub repo for more context https://github.com/vivienphang/job-portal-backend. I can run ``npm start`` but not ``npm run seed``. Any idea what is wrong with my import statement? Mongoose is giving me redline as well - i have ``npm i mongoose`` though.